# Boost LED driver output spikes

Tags: boost, led-driver, ripple-current, spike

I designed a boost LED driver based on TPS92691. It drives 56V 5A COB LED from 22-50V input. It works ok.

Oscilloscope shows small spikes on input (100mV), but large spikes on output (3V). The spikes are from switching (400 kHz).

I started with 4.7uF X7R output capacitor. Then added one more, spikes were reduced. Then added one more, which reduced spikes little more, but adding more capacitance does not change anything anymore.

I mesure with probe with wire coiled around it.

The switcher is powered by separate 12V power, it has 10uF and 1uF caps right next to Vin pin. Every IC has caps near them. Output caps are close to LED wires.

As I understand it, the spike (ringing) happens when MOSFET starts conducting, then when it opens, second, smaller one happens.

Can the spikes be reduced somehow? Also, is it bad, will it harm anything?

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps92691.pdf)

[Schematic](http://www.ti.com.cn/ods/images/ZHCSEM9/Sch_BST_SLVSD68.gif)

[image: Probe]
[image: Output spike]
[image: Output spikes]

[image: Notes]

Comment: Seems many things are going on at the same time on the PCB. Can you perhaps draw on it and show which capacitor bank is which and which part is your main TPS92691? If it’s the guy in the middle, your input and output capacitor banks looks very far away.

Comment: Added the details

Comment: Thanks! Your input and output caps are way too far away! Can you scrape some solderresist away near the switcher to expose Vin and Vout and a nearby GND via and place several caps there? Also, at these high voltages, plastic film comes to mind.

Comment: The switcher is powered by separate 12V power, it has 10uF and 1uF caps right next to Vin pin. Every IC has caps near them. Output caps are close to LED wires.

Comment: Can’t see it. Output caps needs to be within mm of the output choke. LED wires location in s not a concern.

Comment: Can you explain in details. And please describe why, if possible.

Comment: Long distance to caps -> large loop area for the current flow -> high inductance -> lots of energy stored in that inductor -> lots of radiated energy -> fail the EMI tests -> cannot get EMI certification -> cannot market the product -> executives unhappy -> your career is altered.

Comment: PCB trace inductance. Look up an online calculator, enter your figures for the dimensions and distance from output cap to inductor. Enter said inductance between your inductor and output cap in your simulator. Increase output cap like you have in reality and watch how you can’t lower the ripple beyond some level.

Comment: Try some smaller value capacitors, like 0.1uF. They would be better at reducing higher frequency noise.

Comment: The spike (ringing) happens when MOSFET starts conducting, then when it opens, second, smaller one happens.

Comment: This is a quote from the datasheet: "When an output capacitor is used and the LED array is large or separated from the rest of the regulator, the output capacitor should be placed close to the LEDs to reduce the effects of parasitic inductance on the AC impedance of the capacitor."

Comment: @winny you are saying to place output capacitors close to inductor, the datasheet says close to the LED. Which one is correct?

Comment: Whoa! That’s mighty strange. Link to the datasheet? For some true current-stiff driver and feedback located close to the LED, this might be true. Have to think about it.

Comment: In the meantime, we’re you able to scrape any solderresist and add capacitors very close to input and output?

Comment: I just read the datasheet. Still mighty strange. But non the less, take a look at page 38 under layout recommendations. Please note that output capacitor is placed just a few mm from the output inductor and the input cap is just a few mm from the transistor. Time for you to start scraping solderresist!

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: @winny thank you for your suggestions and support. I will redesign the board and place caps close as you suggest. On this board, unfortunately, it is not possible to place caps closer, as there is no ground plane close to output side of the inductor and the diode.

Comment: Wait what? No ground plane? Have you done any EMC measurements on this board? No ground plane is a major warning!

Comment: Man, of course there is a ground plane, it is everywhere :) there is no ground close to the diode and inductor, closest one is where the caps are.

Comment: But the diode is connected to ground!

Comment: Added the schematic. Can you show me where is the diode connected to ground?

Comment: Sorry man, it’s clearly a boost and not buck. Anywho, can you run a piece of copper from the bottom of your sense resistor below the MOSFET (not diode) up to your output diode and place a capacitor there between the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many suggestions here, many of which I will implement in the next version of my board.

In this case, during redesign process, I noticed that the resistor on the current sense RC LPF was shorted, so, there was no LP filtering. I am not sure exactly how it was affecting the circuit, but now it looks much cleaner. The same waveform, but without spikes, just the ripple.

Here is the waveform, probed exactly as in the post above, on output capacitor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your spike is common on hard switched power supplies .It is probably the mosfet ,PCB,coil ,diode capacitance resonating with parasitic inductance in the PCB and in the semiconducter bonding wires .Try gate resistance ,Try better PCB layout,Try DS RC snubber .If you do not improve things you will fail radiated EMC .

Answer (score 0):

The large current spikes are due to operating in the discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) which is inherently noisy at high currents.

**Suggestion:** Change the design to operate in continuous conduction  mode, CCM will reduce the dI/dt significantly from a fast switch transient< 4ns to dI/dt=V/L for the flyback choke slew rate.

Thus if the current slew rate can be reduced such that the bandwidth BW is less than the spurious resonance BW< 0.35/Tr for risetime Tr, there a good chance of noise reduction.

I would guess is an LC tank circuit on the board layout from switched ground path length and Coss FET output capacitance, but non-contact shorted tip probe methods can sniff the current loop to identify the DCM components ( which is also stated in the datasheet).

The 125MHz ringing appears to be the self-resonant (somewhere) that may be located by shorting the 10:1 probe tip to ring and sniffing near-field current transients as a loop antenna.

> is it bad

YES. If this ever becomes a commercial product, it must be certified against unintended radiation to be CE compliant.  Radiating near 120 MHz may interfere with Airport Receivers for example.[image] ;)

Comment: Simulation and measurements show, that it operates in continuous mode.

Comment: THen with shorted probe where is the spike strongest (sniff around), it is not possible.\ for it to be continuous.\ for then there would be no spike.  There must be a missing or poor operating  clamp diode to  decay current slowly.

Comment: I do not know how to use shorted probe. Will read about it and try later.

Comment: just make a small 1 cm diameter loop antenna and sniff around wires for signal

Comment: Is that a 1000 uH inductor for the LED V+? with no caps?  There is something obviously missing or different on your design that you have not told us about that differs from the original design.

Comment: by the way( BTW), the proper way to measure AC noise on any DC power supply is AC coupled with a low R load.  If you have inductive wires to load and Common Mode noise is high then a CM choke with caps to make a Balun with Pi filter is best.

Comment: My board is based on exact schematic from the datasheet. Inductor is 10uH. There are caps. 6 x 4.7uF 100V X7R ceramics.

Comment: Where is the big ferrite inductor labelled with value 103 (1mH), also those caps  are too far apart from IC and 10uH. ( which adds ESL.)

Comment: The inductor is PA4349.103ANLT

Comment: Caps are apart from what? which IC? Please explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92738/discussion-between-roman-simonyan-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).